# how to move Silverlight app to Html5

Tags: html5, silverlight

I have been working with Silverlight 5 application for a while. I liked this technology and I was captivated to the point to get certified in Silverligt development.

However, Html5 gained momentum this point, a new wave of thinking about new applications. Now, i am considering whether to develop in Sl or html5.
I have read thousands of post on the subject and can not find clear if there is any way to migrate an application to HTML5 SL, know if there is any tool to help the process?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question and real ongoing trend in web/mobile development

Comment: If the application is working why migrate it? Who will pay for this?

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Well, for one thing, you will gain support for mobile devices.  Silverlight only runs on Windows Phone, AFAIK.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, thanks for you comment. You are correct, but is support to mobile devices of today a business requirement in Jose's case?

Comment: Silverlight captivated me as well. HTML is a way to render content using a document flow model. Most people designing Silverlight applications were looking to create web applications rather than web sites. Furthermore, many Silverlight developers embraced the MVVM design pattern. In order to carry this forward, I initiated a project to bring these objectives to all platforms and browsers. Check out http://fayde.wsick.com.

Comment: This is a really good specific question of which many people who have invested a lot in Silverlight RIAs would love to hear the answer.

Answer (score 8):

This question is **really important as there is a move to native HTML5 apps**.
I have researched this topic couple months ago, and there are good sources and videos that helped me get glue where to start.

Depending on **how you have build your Silverlight app**, approach/strategy of move various. Here is more details on this topic.

- [HTML5 for Silverlight Developers](http://channel9.msdn.com/events/MIX/MIX11/HTM14)
- [How to replace Flash and Silverlight with HTML5](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/webmaster/how-to-replace-flash-and-silverlight-with-html5/995)
- [From Silverlight to HTML5 - codeproject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/219370/From-Silverlight-To-HTML5)

Comment: Yes, it is indeed a very important question because even Microsoft has dropped the support for Silverlight with their latest browser - Edge.